# Display smileys with html code from TextChoices models

Tags: python-3.x, django, model

I hope you're well,

I've created a `TextChoices models` for my UserProfile. If display data {{ user.userprofile.smiley }} I got the code `&#127814;` but not . Do you have any idea?

I've added this to my settings.py (DB) 'OPTIONS': {'charset': 'utf8mb4'}, the issue is still here. Also change my MYSQL smiley field to utf8mb4_bin...

```
class Smileys(models.TextChoices):
    AUBERGINE = '&#127814;'
    AVOCADO = '&#129361;'
    BROCCOLI = '&#129382;'
    ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    smiley = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Smileys.choices,default=Smileys.CHERRY,)
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) template filter when you want to disable HTML escaping for a string

```
{{ user.userprofile.smiley|safe }}
```

You may expose yourself to XSS attacks if you use this filter on malicious user provided data so be careful